# Android frame by frame animation from png files

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

I'm trying to make frame by frame animation for my game.

I have model designed in Blender and I tried to export animation from Blender as series of *PNG* files and like that to play animation through AnimationDrawable. 
That happens to be a *disaster*. (**slower animation and memory problem**)

I also tried to make my own **animator class** to change the source/background of the *ImageView* and still I have the same problem.

Is there any way I can do this with openGL-ES or something similar but yet easy to use.

*Thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, I did found a solution for this problem.

First thing you need to do is be ready to use some **openGL ES.**

1. Create a square (2 triangles)
2. Place it in the GLSurfaceView
3. Change the texture of the square to create an animation.

This way you will leave the **rendering** to openGL which will do it *faster and smoother*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution Create an animation Drawable and the animating method see code below

```
AnimationDrawable mframeAnimation = null;

private void startAnimation()
{
     ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView_Juggle);

     BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash1); 
     BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash2); 
     BitmapDrawable frame3 = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash3); 

     // Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
     int reasonableDuration = 250;
     mframeAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
     mframeAnimation.setOneShot(false); // loop continuously
     mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame1, reasonableDuration);
     mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame2, reasonableDuration);
     mframeAnimation.addFrame(frame3, reasonableDuration);

     img.setBackgroundDrawable(mframeAnimation);

     mframeAnimation.setVisible(true,true);
     mframeAnimation.start();
}
```

This is just a straight forward method. Better Still create a thread the for animations. You can also create a method to dynamically add the frames. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, gonna try this asap

Comment: Seems as a good solution but there is still some performance issues there.
Loading a lot of images in the same time is memory consuming at any point. There might be a solution with Producer-Consumer implementation with an array (shared buffer) for images (bitmaps) but I believe that it is a major thing to waste any time on implementing that. (I might try that though and will post it on my github).
I found a solution for my problem and it will be posted as the answer here. 
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Load images into a vector/array. Then switch images per frame. Possibly even changing based on time. I have done this opengl but never in opengl-es but this should be very similiar

Comment: Yeah, but what if I have for example 152 frames? That is too memory consuming :/ 
I tried that though, and it makes my HEAP blow up, and it is still slow.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to export your model from Blender not as frames, but to a Collada or 3DSMax object file that contains your 3D model complete with textures and animations.  Then use a library like assimp or the PowerVR SDK or a game engine running on Android to render the model in real time using OpenGL ES.
This would be a bigger project of course, but the size of the data set would be much smaller and give you the ability to change the camera position and lighting at run time.

Comment: This doesnt give me enough triangles for smooth mesh.
And I cannot add fur

Comment: The number of triangles (tessellation) is determined entirely by how you create your model in Blender.

Comment: Yes I know that, but lower the number, lower the smoothness of the model... 
You need to agree :P